# migrate from Joda time library to Java time (Java 8)

Tags: java-8, refactoring, jodatime, java-time

Our software architect made decision to remove Joda time library from our project dependencies and to use features of Java 8 time. I am doing research of our project and I am trying to find all places where we are using Joda time lib and determine what actually we are using (joda `LocalDate`, `DateTime`, etc.).
I am not an expert of Joda time library and I not an expert of Java 8 time, so I have some questions:
In code I saw a lot of places like this:

```
DateTime jodaDateTime = new DateTime();
doSomething(jodaDateTime.toDate());
```

I am a little bit confused.

(**Q1**) Does it make any sense to use joda 
`DateTime` in this particular case? I believe, that we can use just classic `java.util.Date` and we do not need Joda:

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();
doSomething(date);
```

Correct?

Also, I saw this piece of code:

```
org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDateTime = new DateTime();
org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDateTimeInPast = jodaDateTime.minusSeconds(60);
doSomething(jodaDateTimeInPast.toDate());
```

I think, that java 8 time API provides the great support for calculating any dates in the past, so I have idea how to replace the piece of code above to Java 8:

```
LocalDatetime java8DateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocaldateTime java8DateTimeInPast = java8DateTime.minusSeconds(60);
Date java8Date = Date.from(java8DateTimeInPast.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
doSomething(java8Date);
```

(**Q2**) Have I done it in the right way? I am not sure on 100%. 
I just found this link with a table: "[Converting from Joda-Time to java.time](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html)" 
There are I found info, that I need to use `java.time.ZonedDateTime` or `java.time.OffsetDateTime` classes, but not `java.time.LocalDateTime`, because `LocalDateTime` -

> Same concept - date and time without time-zone

Please confirm that my refactoring is correct (for **Q1** and **Q2**).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most questions about conversion should be handled by my [blog](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html) on the topic.

Q1a:
There is no point in creating a Joda-Time object only to change back to `java.util.Date`. However, the method should probbaly take `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
doSomething(instant);  // method changed to take Instant
```

Note that `Instant` is the closest match to `java.util.Date`.

Q1b:
This case involves a time-zone, so should use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime java8DateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();  // uses ZoneId.systemDefault()
ZonedDateTime java8DateTimeInPast = java8DateTime.minusSeconds(60);
doSomething(java8DateTimeInPast.toInstant());
```

Again, this assumes that `doSomething` is changed to take an `Instant`.

The key to using `java.time` properly is to think about what data type is correct for each piece of data.

- Just a date? Then use `LocalDate`
- Just a time? Then use `LocalTime`
- Date, time and time-zone? Then use `ZonedDateTime`
- Just a timestamp with no other info? Then use `Instant`
- A network date-time format with offset (not zone)? Then use `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: you wrote: "Instant is the closest match to java.util.Date", but for example: new Date().toString() returns: Thu Jan 28 18:26:27 EET 2016, but Instant.now().toString() returns: 2016-01-28T16:26:27.210Z. As you can see, Instant returns 16:26:27 and it is UTC, Date returns 18:26:27 - EET

Comment: The `toString()` on `java.util.Date` returns the time in the local time-zone. But the state of the object does not hold that. Understanding that difference is key to understanding `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right for both cases. The only comment I might add that java 8 time supersedes java.util.Date so you might want to think of replacing your methods doSomething(java.util.Date) with doSomething(java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor). However, java.util.Date has not been declared depricated just yet, so you don't have to. In my experience, java 8 time package is very flexible and comprehensive package. I found some funny bugs with Joda even though Joda was a good package for its time.

Comment: `TemporalAccessor` should not be used in most application code. In general, if you are using it outside the lowest level library, you are doing something wrong. In this case, it should be `doSomething(Instant)` or `doSomething(ZonedDateTime)` or similar